# Can I avoid rewriting Devise Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a standard devise edit user form:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, :autocomplete => "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <p>Current Photo</p>
  <%= image_tag @user.photo.url %>

   <%= f.file_field :photo %>

  <div><%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :current_password %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Update" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Now, Rails, obviously complains because of the line: `<%= image_tag @user.photo.url %>` since there isn't an @user in the edit action of the devise controller. Usually, I'd be able to just put @user = current_user in the controller and be done.

The goal is to show the user what their current photo is before they upload a new one. What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If User is the only resource that will use devise, you could use `resource.photo.url`.

If there are some different classes that will authenticate with devise, but will not have a photo, you could use `resource.respond_to?(:photo)` to include the photo and photo fields like this:

```
<% if resource.respond_to?(:photo) %>
  <p>Current Photo</p>
  <%= image_tag resource.photo.url %>

  <%= f.file_field :photo %>
<% end %>
```

That way, you only include the photo information when the class has a photo attribute

Comment: I think you meant when the "object" has a photo :)